# What does "throat-clearing" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> When she triggers Article 50, Mrs May will begin a two-year countdown to Brexit. The first couple of months will bring bureaucratic **throat-clearing** (the European Commission will lead the talks, with the European Council breathing down its neck).

Does it mean bureaucrats will clear their throat in a way that makes mood serious and uncomfortable?

Comment: Please cite the source text when quoting an excerpt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not something that I have heard before (as a native Brit) as being an idiom in this context, so I assume that it is being used metaphorically.

It is a common occurrence for someone to clear their throat (have a small cough) immediately before speaking, in order to make sure they are prepared to speak clearly. The throat-clearing itself (in the literal sense) is not part of the speech, but is just preparation for the main event.

Throat-clearing is therefore sometimes used as a metaphor for this sort of behaviour in a different context - i.e. something is happening or being said, which is probably preamble (setting the scene or talking in vague terms), but is certainly not the main point. I don't think it implies anything about the mood or tone.

Bureaucratic throat-clearing, therefore, would be the bureaucratic preamble to the main Brexit negotiation talks, such as the ground-rules for negotiation.

Comment: So it just imply talk between bureaucrats will happen?

Comment: Yes kind of, but more than that - the talk will all be preamble, not the main Brexit negotiation talks. And the implication is that it will be _bureaucratic_, not necessarily that it will just be between bureaucrats.